# How to use already converted EPS to SVG file in Android

Tags: android, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have a problem with `SVG` files. I used `SVG` file in Android properly.(SVG files which download to internet.) My problem is already converted SVG file. I have EPS files, and I want to use these `EPS` files in Android. For this, I converted `TINY SVG` file via `Adobe Illustrator`. But, these converted files didn't display.

I controlled versions of file. Both of them 1.0 version. I didn't understand why converted files didn't work and why donwloaded `SVG` files worked.

I controlled working `SVG files XML`. These too alredy converted `Adobe Illustrator`. I can't find trick.

Regards

Here is working `SVG` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 13.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 14948)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="max_width__x2F__height" display="none">
    <path display="inline" d="M499.001,1v498H1V1H499.001 M500.001,0H0v500h500.001V0L500.001,0z"/>
</g>
<g id="androd">
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M301.314,83.298l20.159-29.272c1.197-1.74,0.899-4.024-0.666-5.104c-1.563-1.074-3.805-0.543-4.993,1.199
        L294.863,80.53c-13.807-5.439-29.139-8.47-45.299-8.47c-16.16,0-31.496,3.028-45.302,8.47l-20.948-30.41
        c-1.201-1.74-3.439-2.273-5.003-1.199c-1.564,1.077-1.861,3.362-0.664,5.104l20.166,29.272
        c-32.063,14.916-54.548,43.26-57.413,76.34h218.316C355.861,126.557,333.375,98.214,301.314,83.298"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M203.956,129.438c-6.673,0-12.08-5.407-12.08-12.079c0-6.671,5.404-12.08,12.08-12.08
        c6.668,0,12.073,5.407,12.073,12.08C216.03,124.03,210.624,129.438,203.956,129.438"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M295.161,129.438c-6.668,0-12.074-5.407-12.074-12.079c0-6.673,5.406-12.08,12.074-12.08
        c6.675,0,12.079,5.409,12.079,12.08C307.24,124.03,301.834,129.438,295.161,129.438"/>
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M126.383,297.598c0,13.45-10.904,24.354-24.355,24.354l0,0c-13.45,0-24.354-10.904-24.354-24.354V199.09
        c0-13.45,10.904-24.354,24.354-24.354l0,0c13.451,0,24.355,10.904,24.355,24.354V297.598z"/>
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M140.396,175.489v177.915c0,10.566,8.566,19.133,19.135,19.133h22.633v54.744
        c0,13.451,10.903,24.354,24.354,24.354c13.451,0,24.355-10.903,24.355-24.354v-54.744h37.371v54.744
        c0,13.451,10.902,24.354,24.354,24.354s24.354-10.903,24.354-24.354v-54.744h22.633c10.569,0,19.137-8.562,19.137-19.133V175.489
        H140.396z"/>
    <path fill="#9FBF3B" d="M372.734,297.598c0,13.45,10.903,24.354,24.354,24.354l0,0c13.45,0,24.354-10.904,24.354-24.354V199.09
        c0-13.45-10.904-24.354-24.354-24.354l0,0c-13.451,0-24.354,10.904-24.354,24.354V297.598z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here is not working `SVG` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1 Tiny//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-tiny.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_extend "http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_ai "http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_graphs "http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_vars "http://ns.adobe.com/Variables/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_imrep "http://ns.adobe.com/ImageReplacement/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_sfw "http://ns.adobe.com/SaveForWeb/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_custom "http://ns.adobe.com/GenericCustomNamespace/1.0/">
    <!ENTITY ns_adobe_xpath "http://ns.adobe.com/XPath/1.0/">
]>
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="792px"
     viewBox="0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<switch>
    <foreignObject requiredExtensions="&ns_ai;" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
        <i:pgfRef  xlink:href="#adobe_illustrator_pgf">
        </i:pgfRef>
    </foreignObject>
    <g i:extraneous="self">
        <g>

                <image width="107" height="148" xlink:href="data:image 
//and goind to very long...
```

My Main Activity :

```
package com.example.svgexample4;

import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG;
import com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    ImageView myImg;
    SVG svgFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);


        myImg = new ImageView(this);

        myImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        SVG svgFile = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.egg_purple_svg);
        myImg.setImageDrawable(svgFile.createPictureDrawable());

        mainLayout.addView(myImg);
        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: "didn't display" is not an especially helpful description of your symptoms. How are you trying to display the SVG?

Comment: I added main activity. Image didn't display. Average image size, black label display.

Answer (score 0):

svg-android only supports a small subset of the SVG spec.  You could try my renderer [AndroidSVG](http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) which supports a bit more of the spec and aims to support files generated by Illustrator (like your "not working" file).

If it doesn't render with AndroidSVG, file a bug and I will try to fix it.